# Pointers and references (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers

This `while` does not halt and appears to stuck in an endless loop:

```
struct list_elem<int[5]> *p, *pCopy; // list_elem is  the node struct
p = l.pfirst;                        // l is the LL object

pCopy = p->next;

while(p != NULL) { 
   //bunch of code
   p = pCopy; 
}
```

**Will close the question**

Simply `pCopy` was a constant because it was out side the loop.
Thank you for helping

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: the while loop never ends with p=pCopy

Comment: You haven't given us enough code to determine what's wrong, but I don't see why a `remove` method should be *changing* values in the list. Tell us more about what you're trying to do, give us code we can compile and run, and maybe we can help.

Comment: (Also, I hope you realize that the `while` loop you've shown us never changes `pCopy`.)

Comment: @Beta oh!!, this probably is the problem thanks, i will check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you iterate:

```
while(p != NULL) { 
   p = p->next; 
}
```

The `.` operator is used for local structs whereas the `->` dereferences a pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct my_struct {

    int id;
    struct my_struct *next;    
}

int main()
{
    struct my_struct *a, *b, *c;

    a = malloc(sizeof(struct my_struct));
    b = malloc(sizeof(struct my_struct));
    c = malloc(sizeof(struct my_struct));

    a->next = b;
    a->id = 1;

    b->next = c;
    b->id = 2;

    c->next = NULL;
    c->id = 3;

    struct my_struct *it = a;

    printf("Using pointers:\n\n");

    while(it != NULL) {
        printf("Element %d\n", it->id);

        it = it->next;
    }

    struct my_struct d, e, f;

    d.next = &e;
    d.id = 1;

    e.next = &f;
    e.id = 2;

    f.next = NULL;
    f.id = 3;

    it = &d;

    printf("Using locals:\n\n");

    while(it != NULL) {
        printf("Element %d\n", it->id);

        it = (it->next);
    }

    free(a);
    free(b);
    free(c);

    return 0;
}
```

You should google a tutorial on C and first in line try to understand *pointer arithmetic*.

Comment: thanks
what i meant was that dont explain much,
anyway i edited my post because that was a useless information and i also googled it, otherwise i wouldnt have been able to write what i have.

Comment: So is my answer okay or do you have another question?

Comment: the code crashes while running, but it is not because i dont understand something new in C++, it is because i didnt work hard enough, so thank you, i will ask again when i am hopeless

Comment: Okay. But take a look at my edited answer anyway.

Comment: Please call `free`. Please. It bothers me that the memory is not freed in this post. I will +1 you if you do.

Comment: :D I was already about to do it but you are right, one should never forget to free the memory!

Comment: @StefanR.Falk, thanks for the update, this is my actual code http://bit.ly/QMLQ55 it is still a mess with many cout indicators for me, if you donty mind, take a look :)

Comment: @Fanckush sorry I don't have an IDE available at the moment so I cannot test your code. I hope my answer could help you so far but here is a little suggestion: Your code style is not very uniform/consistent. Try to clean up your code a little (which is a very important practice) and try to stick to one readable programming style like use whitespaces instead of tabs, write `if` in two lines or add scope clamps `if { }` and so on. And don't do stuff like `cout<<*(p[0].info + i)<<" ";` instead make it `cout << *(p[0].info + i) << " ";` and so on :) happy coding.

Comment: ok, will do make it better, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((p = p->next) != NULL);
```

What you have isn't actually going through the list, just setting itself the same over and over